# arcpy - decimal value for labelling

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, labeling

i have field named (depth) in feature class (point) with this spec :

float - 5 digits  >>>  0.7186   or 0.9695

i create new field named (depth_new) with field calculator : round([depth],1)
the result will be >>>  0.7186 = 0.7  or 0.9695 = 1

then i want to use (depth_new) field as label in my point feature class using arcpy, here is some of my statement in my code :

```
      lyr.labelClasses[0].expression = '"{}" & (left([depth_new],1)) & " " & "<SUB>" & (right( [depth_new],1)) & "</SUB>" & "{}"'.format("<FNT size = '17'><CLR blue = '255'>","</CLR></FNT>")
```

it is works fine,
but as you can see on my code, i use "right" and "left" for the digit of the number that i want to show as label,

the problem is lets take a look at record with value = 0.7 it will be come 0.7 , but with value = 1 , the label will be 1.1 (so the number is changed, the correct should be 1.0)

i know i can solve this in field properties and check "pad with zeroes" and use 2 digit in properties, but let say i have 100 layers, so should i really do that for every 100 layers? i use arcpy for labelling to skip repitition and save time,

so any workaround or alternative way for this?

Answer (score 1):

It is a formatting issue. Indeed, you could compute the rounding while formatting the value.

Using this [doc](https://pyformat.info/#number_padding), we see that we can specify (or not) a total output length, a padding for the units and a padding for the decimals.

Since you want only to pad 1 decimal with 0, the formatting code would be

```
'{:.1f}'.format(1)
'1.0'
'{:.1f}'.format(0.123)
'0.1'
```